# How do I repeat counting on my page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to make my counting information repeat when it comes to specific value, and I need that repeat continues all the time (I have starting and ending value).

My code is below :

```
<?php if ($fact_one !='') : ?>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
 <div class="roll-counter">
    <i class="fa <?php echo $fact_one_icon; ?>"></i>
    <div class="name-count"><?php echo $fact_one; ?></div>
    <div class="numb-count" data-from="1716164" data-to="11569734" data-speed="1000" data-waypoint-active="yes"><?php echo $fact_one_max; ?></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Numbering where/what exactly?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? What's your data? Are you using any JavaScript frameworks/plugins that uses those `data-*` attributes you're setting?

Comment: A good way to explain what you want is to show examples of expected results.

Comment: it's widget on my wordpress theme. data is some numbers whos simulating daily counting.

Comment: Sorry for bad explain.

Comment: Iam using some wordpress theme with counting widget, and now i want to repet count when it comes to "data-to="11569734"" and start again from "data-from="1716164"". And i need that repet function tocontinue all the time.

Comment: If you want the count to change without the page reloading, then that's a JavaScript question, which probably already has an answer, somewhere...